# how can i optimize the VBA code for formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have below code which will help me to do some formatting. but i want increase the efficiency of the code by reducing the time. Below are the formatting steps which macro will be doing.

- 1. Convert "Q" and "S" column" to number format.
  2. Replicate the "I" column to  new column by inserting column next to it.
  3. Cut the Column "AD" and paste to column "O".
  4. Remove columns ("A:A,AD:AG")
  5. Replace "#" with null and "OUT" with P input value in "AC" column.
  6. Round the "Q" and "S" column numbers to 2 decimal.
  7. Change the sign of values in column Q by multiplying  -1(*-1)
  8. Filter on "Q" column with "0" and filter on "S" column with "0". Then 
     remove those rows with "Q" and "S" is  Zero.
  9. Filter 0 on Q column, Clear only visible cells of "Q" and "R" Columns.
  10. Filter 0 on "S" column, Clear only visible cells of "S" and "T" Columns.
  11. Copy the headers (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("A20:AC20").Copy) and 
      paste to the A1 of file formatted.
  12. Remove all columns and rows which doesn’t  have data apart from used 
      range.

Currently macro working fine but taking some time.As i am new to VBA not sure how to optimize the code. Hence i here looking for help from experts. Thanks in advance.

Below is the code

```
Sub Ananplan_to_BPM()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Lastcol As Long
Dim P As String
 'Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
'The path for the file picked will be stored in fullpath variable
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        '.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb; *.csv"
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show
        'Store in fullpath variable
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
    'It's a good idea to still check if the file type selected is accurate.
    'Quit the procedure if the user didn't select the type of file we need.
    If InStr(fullpath, ".xls") = 0 Then
    If InStr(fullpath, ".csv") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    End If
 'Open the file selected by the user
    Workbooks.Open fullpath
    P = InputBox("Please Enter the Version")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveWorkbook
    Columns(17).NumberFormat = "0"
    Columns(19).NumberFormat = "0"
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Columns("I").Copy
    Columns("I").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    'Range("AE2").Value = P
    'Range("AE2", "AE" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
    Columns("AE").Copy
    Columns("P").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A,AE:AG").EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns("AC").Replace What:="#", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("AC").Replace What:="OUT", Replacement:=P, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("AD2").Formula = "=Round(Q2,2)"
    Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
    Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("Q2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("AD2").Formula = "=Round(S2,2)"
    Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
    Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("S2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("AD2").Formula = "=(Q2*-1)"
    Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
    Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    Range("Q2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Columns("AD:AD").EntireColumn.Delete
With ActiveSheet.Range("A:AC")
    .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="0"
    .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="0"
    .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="0"
    .Range("Q2:R" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="0"
    .Range("S2:T" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear
    .AutoFilter
    '.Range("C2").AutoFill .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
End With
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("A20:AC20").Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Rows("1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete
'ActiveWorkbook.Save
'ActiveWorkbook.Close
MsgBox "Done With Farmatting"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a site for reviewing code. There is another one, especially for that purpose in the *StackOverflow* family. I nevertheless reviewed your code and found nothing that I might point to to make it slow in particular. There should be ways to do the job faster but they require knowledge of your intentions. It seems you have a big worksheet. So it may take a little time but not enough to have a coffee. My comments, therefore, focus on the code's inherent imprecision which makes it prone to crash as well as prone to do untold damage if it's let lose on the wrong worksheet. I have added comments.

```
Sub Ananplan_to_BPM()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim P As String

    ' Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
    ' The path for the file picked will be stored in fullpath variable
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        ' Makes sure the user can select only one file - quite the opposite
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        '.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb; *.csv"
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show
        'Store in fullpath variable
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With

    ' It's a good idea to still check if the file type selected is accurate.
    If InStr(fullpath, ".xls") = 0 Or InStr(fullpath, ".csv") = 0 Then
        ' Quit the procedure if the user didn't select the type of file we need.
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Open the file selected by the user
    Workbooks.Open fullpath
    P = InputBox("Please Enter the Version")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveWorkbook
        ' There isn't a single reference to the ActiveWorkbook
        ' in the entire 'With' bracket.
        ' Create a link to the 'With' object by a leading period.
        ' Example:-
'        With .Worksheets(1)                 ' linked to ActiveWorkbook
'            ' below, both cells and Rows.Count of Worksheets(1)
'            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
'        End With

        ' which sheet are you working on here?
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Columns(17).NumberFormat = "0"
        Columns(19).NumberFormat = "0"
        Columns("I").Copy
        Columns("I").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        'Range("AE2").Value = P
        'Range("AE2", "AE" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
        Columns("AE").Copy
        Columns("P").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        ' You didn't activate any sheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:A,AE:AG").EntireColumn.Delete
        ' everything you do above or below this line
        '' is done to the ActiveSheet


        Columns("AC").Replace What:="#", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                              SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        Columns("AC").Replace What:="OUT", Replacement:=P, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                              SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        ' This should probably be done using a cell format.
        ' If you need rounded values in later calculations do
        ' the rounding in later calculations, not in the original data.
        Range("AD2").Formula = "=Round(Q2,2)"
        Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
        Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        Range("Q2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Range("AD2").Formula = "=Round(S2,2)"
        Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
        Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        Range("S2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Range("AD2").Formula = "=(Q2*-1)"
        Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
        Range("AD2", "AD" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        Range("Q2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Columns("AD:AD").EntireColumn.Delete
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:AC")
        ' This method will throw an error if there are no visible cells
        ' why not suppress the display of zero with a CellFormat?
        .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="0"
        .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="0"
        .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="0"
        .Range("Q2:R" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="0"
        .Range("S2:T" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Clear
        .AutoFilter
        '.Range("C2").AutoFill .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool").Range("A20:AC20").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    ' you are still working on the undefined ActiveSheet
    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Rows("1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireColumn.Delete
    'ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'ActiveWorkbook.Close
    MsgBox "Done With Formatting"
End Sub
```